# vertica select stament with groupby function doesn't work

Tags: subquery, apache-spark-sql, vertica, correlated-subquery

The query running well through vertica, but it doesn't work in jdbc "pyspark",

> ERROR: Syntax error at or near "\"

Even after removing the \$condtion, it returns

> "ERROR: Subquery in FROM must have an alias"

```
SELECT 
 min(date(time_stamp)) mindate
,max(date(time_stamp)) maxdate
,count (distinct date(time_stamp)) noofdays
, subscriber
, server_hostname
, sum(bytes_in) DL
, sum(bytes_out) UL
, sum(connections_out) conn 
from traffic.stats 
where \$CONDITIONS 
and SUBSCRIBER like '41601%' 
and date(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' and '2019-01-29'
and signature_service_category = 'Web Browsing' 
and (signature_service_name = 'SSL v3' 
  or signature_service_name = 'HTTP2 over TLS') 
and server_hostname not like '%.googleapis.%' 
and server_hostname not like '%.google.%' 
and server_hostname <> 'doubleclick.net'  
and server_hostname <> 'youtube.com'  
and server_hostname <> 'googleadservices.com'  
and server_hostname <> 'app-measurement.com' 
and server_hostname <> 'gstatic.com' 
and server_hostname <> 'googlesyndication.com' 
and server_hostname <> 'google-analytics.com'  
and server_hostname <> 'googleusercontent.com'  
and server_hostname <> 'ggpht.com'  
and server_hostname <> 'googletagmanager.com' 
and server_hostname is not null 
group by subscriber, server_hostname
```

I have tried the above query on pyspark 1.6

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel
from pyspark.streaming import DStream
from pyspark.streaming.dstream import TransformedDStream
from pyspark.streaming.util import TransformFunction
from pyspark.rdd import RDD
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
import string
import re
import sys,os
import pandas




conf = (SparkConf()
.setAppName("hivereader")
.setMaster("yarn-client")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
.set("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
.set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
.set("spark.executor.instances", 7)
.set("spark.executor.cores" , 7)
.set("spark.sql.inMemoryStorage.compressed", "true")
.set("spark.sql.tungsten.enabled" , 'true')
.set("spark.port.maxRetries" , 200)


)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)



url = "jdbc:vertica*****************"
properties = {
    "user": "********",
    "password": "******",
    "driver": "com.vertica.jdbc.Driver"
}
query = "SELECT MIN(date(time_stamp)) mindate, MAX(date(time_stamp)) maxdate,COUNT (distinct date(time_stamp)) noofdays, subscriber, server_hostname, SUM(bytes_in) DL, SUM(bytes_out) UL, SUM(connections_out) conn FROM traffic.stats t WHERE SUBSCRIBER LIKE '41601%' AND date(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' and '2019-01-29'AND signature_service_category = 'Web Browsing' AND signature_service_name IN ('SSL v3',  'HTTP2 over TLS')AND server_hostname IS NOT NULL AND server_hostname NOT LIKE '%.googleapis.%' AND server_hostname NOT LIKE '%.google.%' AND server_hostname NOT IN ( 'doubleclick.net', 'youtube.com', 'googleadservices.com', 'app-measurement.com', 'gstatic.com', 'googlesyndication.com', 'google-analytics.com', 'googleusercontent.com', 'ggpht.com', 'googletagmanager.com') GROUP BY subscriber, server_hostname"
df = sqlContext.read.format("JDBC").options(
    url = url,
    dbtable="( " + query + " ) as temp",
    **properties
).load()

df.show(50)
```

at the end of the query I have added "as x" and at the beginning "select * from(normal query)" its worked but without showing any result , spark 1.6 doesn't allow us to use direct query that's why I have tried to as temp db.table

Comment: May be a transcription error but the space between count and ( is not allowed at  count (distinct date

Comment: I removed that thing , but still same problem

Comment: Is stats a table or a view?

Comment: This is not a Spark error. It is a Vertica error. All subqueries must have an alias. For example, on your Vertica cluster, try running the following query.

`SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT * FROM nodes
);`

You will get the error:

`[Code: 4833, SQL State: 42601]  [Vertica][VJDBC](4833) ERROR: Subquery in FROM must have an alias`

Will you please post your "ENTIRE" pyspark code (not just the sql query) so that I can take a look at the whole picture?

Comment: sure , I really respect you effort sir, now I will view whole picture

Comment: @A.Saunders , its ready sir.

Comment: @NikolanAsad I have downloaded Spark 1.6. I have created a table similar to the one you are trying to query and I have run the same code that you have, but I am not getting any errors, and when I run `df.show()` I am seeing the result. This is quite a puzzling problem. I am sorry I couldn't be more helpful. I can only say that the error `Subquery in FROM must have an alias` is coming from Vertica and not Spark. I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your effort :)

Comment: Saw that this was still unanswered. Question, why did you tag mysql? Aren't you querying Vertica?